Adjusting VAR-coefficients for simulation
I am estimating a VAR-model, which I then use for Monte Carlo simulations. However, for some of the variables there is a clear downward trend in the data which we don't want to include in our simulations. My colleagues suggested I could just put the trend-coefficient to zero in the simulation to get the right results. However, I am wondering whether that is okay in this case or that it will break down all the other coefficients because of the interdependent nature of the coefficients in the VAR-model.
Also, when I put the trend to zero, I need to adjust the coefficient for the mean so that it will align with a value close to the mean at the end of the estimation period, instead of the overall mean. So, we want to target a specific geometric mean. What is the best way to go about changing my model for these wishes?
